# golang Read(p []byte) does not read full byte?

Tags: go, io

Recently I use golang `Read(p []byte)`,intending to read full `len(p)` bytes. However I find that `Read` does not guarantee read `len(p)` bytes.  That's, I need read 4 bytes but actually it gives me only 1. At last I use `io.ReadFull` instead.

Now I am confused, what's the meaning of the function? What's the proper scene using Read? It may just read less bytes than you need.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the documentation states. Take a look at how Read is used throughout the stdlib is you are unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation and the source code, you will realize why the [`bufio.Read(p []byte)`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read) does not guarantee the full read of data into `p Reader`.

> Read reads data into p. It returns the number of bytes read into p.
>   The bytes are taken from at most one Read on the underlying Reader,
>   hence n may be less than len(p).

Copying from the source code, at the end of the function there is a `copy` operation where the buffer is copied into the byte array. But this does not guarantee that the full chunk of data is copied.

```
// copy as much as we can
n = copy(p, b.buf[b.r:b.w]) // => this line is important
b.r += n
b.lastByte = int(b.buf[b.r-1])
b.lastRuneSize = -1
return n, nil
```

If you wish to copy the full length of bytes use [`bufio.ReadBytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadBytes) instead, using `EOF` or `EOL` delimiter as parameter, depending on your use case.